# How to make a Textbox in Visual Studio enter as a webhook for discord

Tags: c#, .net

So, I've been trying for a while now. I cant seem to get this to work.

```
| // A TextBox
U

string Webhook = "" + Webhook.a.Text + ""; // The Line I Need Help With
```

Whole source

```
public static void WebHookConnector(string content)
{
        string Webhook = "" + Webhook.a.Text + "";

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpClient().PostAsync(Webhook, (HttpContent)new MultipartFormDataContent()
        {
        {
            (HttpContent) new StringContent("Flux"),
            "username"
        },
        {
            (HttpContent) new StringContent("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/546454381340655617/546461512370356244/flux_logo.png"),
            "avatar_url"
        },
        {
            (HttpContent) new StringContent(content),
            "content"
        }
        }).Result;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred in process");
        }
}
```

If your reading this and your helping me thanks! I'm still learning!

Comment: Its not really clear what you are asking for. But one mistake i saw is, you have a duplicated variable name with `string Webhook` and `Webhook.a.Text`. Not sure what the second Webhook is. A form with a TextBox named `a`?

Comment: What im trying to do is I want to make the user put his custom webhook for testing. Custom Logo ect.